# Google map : PHP - Map marker bounce when clicking on button

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Stuck on the map marker bounce.I am showing a multiple location using marker on map dynamically. When i click on event button(Map icon), on map same location bounce.

Sharing my code:

Here is my view

[image]

What i want that, When i am clicking on map icon in Activity same marker on map with lat-long will bounce.Same for all.

Here is my a href link for map

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
 // here i gt latitude and longitude
```

Google map script:

```
 <script>

        function initMap() {
            window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                <?php 
                    if($listactivity !="" && count($listactivity)>0){
                    foreach($listactivity as $location){ ?>
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng({{ $location->latitude }}, {{ $location->longitude }});
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: location,
                      map: map
                    });


                bounds.extend(marker.position);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                }));

                <?php }} ?>

            map.fitBounds(bounds);

            var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
                if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16); 
                google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
            });
        }


        </script>
```

How can i do it dynamically.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure of what you mean by bounce? Are all the markers showing the same infowindow? Do you want a different infowindow for each marker? Is the issue something else?

Comment: I am showing all my location on map with marker, as you can see on map there is four location added.On activity lists contain every activity have lat-long which i show on map.now i want when someone clicking on map marker icon covered by black box..it is tickle on map.so user can identify that.am interested in this location.

Comment: Ok I understand, but the **Bounce** and **Drop** animations are only available for marker creation. You can't use them for anything beyond that.

Comment: You can change the animation dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do:

```
// Pushing all markers to an object with an ID, after the end of your php for loop, with the current loop variable, in this case use for cycle instead of foreach
<script>
var markers = [];
    function initMap() {
        window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            <?php 
                if($listactivity !="" && count($listactivity)>0){
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($listactivity); $i++){ ?>
                        var currentIndex = {{ $i }}
                        var location = new google.maps.LatLng({{ $listactivity[$i]->latitude }}, {{ $listactivity[$i]->longitude }});
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: location,
                            map: map
                        });
                        markers.push({id: currentIndex, marker: marker});

                        bounds.extend(marker.position);
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                          return function () {
                             infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                             infowindow.open(map, marker);
                          }
                    }));
            <?php }} ?>

        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
            if (map.getZoom() > 16) map.setZoom(16); 
            google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
        });
    }

    // Setting up click event

    $('.markericon').on('click', function () {
        var markerId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var result = $.grep(markers, function (e) {
            if (e.id == markerId) {
                return e;
            }
        });
        // Trigger marker click event, or bounce effect.
        google.maps.event.trigger(result[0].marker, 'click');
    });

    </script>



// Adding a markericon class, and storing the location's marker id in a data attribute
// e.g <a href="#" class="markericon" data-id="1">
```

Comment: can you please set on above code..as i ma gtng error

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`